# VBA calling vbs file form Program Files, won't call

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I currently have the following code to call a vbs file that is in a folder within Program Files. It was originally in a different location (within the same folder) and it would work, but now there is a padlock symbol next to the folder within Program Files, and after changing the location (VBA updated for this as well), it won't call the file. I'm wondering why this is happening.

```
Sub ChangeThemeBasic()

Dim filespe As String
filespe = "cmd.exe /c C:\Program Files\Theme Changer\ChangeTheme.vbs"
X = Shell(filespe, 1)

End Sub
```

EDIT:

This works for some reason, I don't know why though:

```
Sub Test()
Shell "Explorer.exe ""C:\Program Files\Theme Changer\ChangeTheme.vbs""",1
End Sub
```

Comment: what OS version?  you may need elevated privileges to access Program Files

Comment: Windows 7 Professional SP1

Comment: Well I am sending this code out to some friends as well, and I have a batch file that moves the folder to program files so it is easily accessible. I need to make sure VBA can run the files in it on anyone's computer. I can go into the folder and click the file and it does what I want it to do. But it doesn't seem to read from VBa :/

Comment: what about using the appdata directory?  Environ("AppData") to get the location.

Comment: You mean place the folder in AppData instead?

Comment: I could do this, but also I just tried something and it made it work, but i have no idea why, it seems it should do the exact same thing. Refer to my edit.

Answer (score 1):

From comments

```
Sub ChangeThemeBasic()

Dim filespe As String
filespe = "cmd.exe /c " & Environ("AppData") & "\Theme Changer\ChangeTheme.vbs"
X = Shell(filespe, 1)

End Sub
```